# Switching tab in GateIn doesn't make Vaadin portlet's content rendered

Tags: vaadin, portlet, gatein

Switching a tab in GateIn doesn't make Vaadin portlet's content rendered. The only way to get the content of some tab rendered is to select the tab and refresh the page. Is there a way to resolve this problem?
Here is the example code of the portlet:

```
@Widgetset("ru.example.widgetset.ExampleWidgetset")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("reindeer")
public class Form1UI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = Form1UI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSizeFull();
        setContent(layout);

        Table table = new Table("The Brightest Stars");

        table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
        table.addContainerProperty("Mag",  Float.class, null);

        Object newItemId = table.addItem();
        Item row1 = table.getItem(newItemId);
        row1.getItemProperty("Name").setValue("Sirius");
        row1.getItemProperty("Mag").setValue(-1.46f);

        table.addItem(new Object[]{"Canopus",        -0.72f}, 2);
        table.addItem(new Object[]{"Arcturus",       -0.04f}, 3);
        table.addItem(new Object[]{"Alpha Centauri", -0.01f}, 4);


        layout.addComponent(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some further informations?  e.g. are there errors in the logs or exceptions?  what versions do you use?  could you provide a code snippet, that shows the problem?

Comment: No errors, no exceptions, I use Vaadin 7.3.6 and GateIn 3.8.1.Final, I've added a simple code snippet above. All works as expected except for the tab switching. Tab container comes with GateIn.